# Multiple MapViews in fragments bug, all maps visible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I am using a single activity with multiple frgmetns where each holds a MapView in its fragment.

This is a reported bug, that i occurs on 4.0.4 android (probably on 4.0 also) but works properly on higher versions.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027

[Multiple maps v2 in TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585409/multiple-maps-v2-in-tabactivity)

When a new fragment is added both maps show. If a third fragment is added all tree maps are shown. I have tried applying the hideStupidMaps fix as discussed above but it provides no result( i have added calls to hide/show maps in onResume/onPause).

I have also added calls to hide the previous map before calling FragmentManager and its transaction but no result.

I have tried setting MapView visibility to INVISIBLE but also no result, the map previos map still shows, like no refresh is happening?

Is there a way to set zIndex to MapView? I know you can set z index when using MapFragment through GoogleOptions but i cant find an option to do that with MapView?

```
   GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
   options.zOrderOnTop(true);
   fragmentMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided in your link? like changing "add" to "replace" for fragments? There seems to be several working solutions...

Comment: Yes i tried using replace but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working. The problem was that i was actually calling hideStupidMaps after fragment transaction, and on 4.0.4 android it didnt have any effect while it worked on 4.1. I moved the call before the Fragment transaction and it worked. The only downfall is that for a moment the user can see the map disappear before Fragment animation starts.

I have also added a OnBackStackChangedListener where i would show the previously hidden map when returning via back button/action bar.

Hope it helps someone, and a piece of advise, avoid multiple maps in fragments if you can...