# Issue while using 2 map fragments in One application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, supportmapfragment

I am trying to use two different Map Fragment in two different Fragment Activities. And as per the SupportMapFragment design, I am keeping the map key in the META TAG of the appilcation properties in Manifest file. 
 However my Map view is not clearing, it is showing same map with old points in the second Fragment eventhough I am calling "getMap().clear()". Please suggest

This is working fine untill and unless I dont use new MapFragment in a separate Activity, If I use new Mapfragment, it is taking the same map view, so the map view is not clearing.

Code :

MAP FRAGMENT

public class DisplayMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements
        OnMarkerClickListener,OnInfoWindowClickListener {

```
View mMapViewContainer;
MapView mMapView;

private Utill utilClass = Utill.getInstance(false);
private View v;
private MapView mapView;
private GeoPoint p;
private MapController mc;
private String latstr = "";
private String lonstr = "";
private String name, address;
private double lat;
private double lng;

ArrayList<NearByItem> NearByList=new ArrayList<NearByItem>();
private LatLng mPosFija;
private ArrayList<Double> mlat, mlong;
private ViewGroup parent;
Utill utilclass=Utill.getInstance(false);
Bitmap bmp;
ImageView ivIcon;
StringBuilder sbc=new StringBuilder();

ProgressBar progressbar;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;     
public DisplayMapFragment() {
    super();

}

public static DisplayMapFragment newInstance(LatLng posicion) {
    DisplayMapFragment frag = new DisplayMapFragment();
    frag.mPosFija = posicion;
    return frag;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    NearByList=NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists;
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    mlat = new ArrayList<Double>();
    mlong = new ArrayList<Double>();
    parent=arg1;
    if(NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists!=null && !NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists.isEmpty())
            NearByList.addAll(NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists);
    else
        NearByList.addAll(Utill.NearbyList);


    NearByMapActivity parentActivity = (NearByMapActivity) getActivity();

    return v;
}

public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items;
    private Drawable marker;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        marker = defaultMarker;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }

    public void addItem(OverlayItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void populateNow() {
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {

        return true;
    }

}

private void initMap() {

    UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
    settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    // settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    settings.isZoomControlsEnabled();
    getMap().setTrafficEnabled(true);
    getMap().getMaxZoomLevel();
    // getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if(NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists!=null && !NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists.isEmpty())
    getMap().moveCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists.get(0).getLocationLat()), 
                            Double.parseDouble(NearByMapActivity.fltrdNearByLists.get(0).getLocationLong())), 14));
    getMap().isTrafficEnabled();
    // getMap().addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().)

    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

            marker=new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(
                                        Double.parseDouble(item.getLocationLat()), 
                                        Double.parseDouble(item.getLocationLong())))
                        .title(""+item.getStoreTitle())
                        .icon(bitmapLoyalty
                                ).snippet(sbc.toString());
        else
            marker=new MarkerOptions()
        .position(
                new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(item.getLocationLat()), 
                        Double.parseDouble(item.getLocationLong())))
        .title(""+item.getStoreTitle())
        .icon(bitmapIconNearBy
                ).snippet(sbc.toString());



Marker marker1=getMap().addMarker(marker);

PopupWindowAdapter view1=new PopupWindowAdapter();

this.getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(view1);


        // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.orgr_icon);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initMap();
     getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new
LatLng(36.865814,-119.758399)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red_pin)));
     //getMap().addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlay(null));
```

/*       getMap().addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
         .image(image)
         .positionFromBounds(bounds)
         .transparency(0.5));
*/  }

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

//getMap().clear();
}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(NearByMapActivity.mainMapView!=null)
        //if(NearByMapActivity.mainMapView.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
                NearByMapActivity.mainMapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("cleared", "");
    return false;
}

}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    //getMap().clear();
}
```

}

MAP ACTIVITY : Activity class to start Fragment.

```
public class NearByMapActivity extends FragmentActivity{

onCreate(){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag=new DisplayMapFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.middle_view, frag);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show us some of your implementation?

Comment: @Warpzit: I updated my code. please have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You are probably affected by this bug:
 https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027&thanks=5027&ts=1362071369

Answer (score 0):

Thank u so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I try this, and its work like a charm :)

```
public void hideStupidMaps() {
        mMapView.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        mMapView.getLayoutParams().width = 1;
        mMapView.invalidate();
        mMapView.requestLayout();

    }
```