# Only first map is showing with Multiple SupportMapFragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, supportmapfragment

**Background**

I have a viewpager with three fragments. All the fragments are the new instance of the same fragment class that uses custom map layout or listview depending on the App Settings. But the problem only in map mode.

**Problem**

Every time I start viewpager activity in the map mode only current fragment shows the map. Other fragments are empty. Looks like all the fragments uses the only instance of map. And current fragment get this map first. Maps in other two fragments are null.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
            layout="@layout/loading_component"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapFragmentHole"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cur_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/map_compas"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_back"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_theatre"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/go_to_list_button_bg"
            android:text="@string/return_to_list"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```java
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                return CinemaAllFragment.newInstance(modeFavourite);
                //return new CinemaFavouriteFragment();

            }
            if (i == 1) {
                return CinemaAllFragment.newInstance(modeOnline);
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                return CinemaAllFragment.newInstance(modeDefault);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.frame_cinema_title1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.frame_cinema_title2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.frame_cinema_title4);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**My Fragment**

```java
public class CinemaAllFragment extends CinemaFragment implements LocationListener {
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private GoogleMap map = null;

private Marker myPosition;
private View balloon;

private Button curLocationBtn;

protected ListView listViewCinemas = null;
protected View view;

private String fragmentMode;
private static String MODE = "mode";
private static String modeFavourite = "modeFavourite";
private static String modeOnline = "modeOnline";
private static String modeDefault = "modeDefault";
private Cinema[] cinemas;
private Long updateTime;
private Long lastUpdate;


private CinemaListArrayAdapter adapter = null;

private static String FRAGMENT = "position";

private ArrayList<Marker> Markers;

private long nowTime;

// Handler to update UI timeFr, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable onEveryFiveMinutes;

private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = null;

public static CinemaAllFragment newInstance(String someString)
{
    CinemaAllFragment myFragment = new CinemaAllFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(MODE, someString);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    if(getArguments()!=null)
        fragmentMode = getArguments().getString(MODE, null);

    if (Settings.getCinemaTypeView() == Settings.CinemaTypeView.Map)
    {
        mLog.d("OnCreate: map "+fragmentMode);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_map, container, false);

        GoogleMapOptions gmo = (new GoogleMapOptions()).zoomControlsEnabled(true).rotateGesturesEnabled(false);

        if(supportMapFragment == null)
            supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(gmo);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapFragmentHole, supportMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        balloon = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_list_item, null);

        ImageView delimiter = (ImageView) balloon.findViewById(R.id.delimiter);
        delimiter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    else if (Settings.getCinemaTypeView() == Settings.CinemaTypeView.Listing)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_list, container, false);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (Settings.getCinemaTypeView() == Settings.CinemaTypeView.Map)
    {
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    onUpdate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (Settings.getCinemaTypeView() == Settings.CinemaTypeView.Map)
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(supportMapFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

class CustomInfoAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        displayView(marker);

        if(!marker.getTitle().equals("Я"))
        {
            return balloon;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void displayView(Marker marker) {

    TextView cinema_title = (TextView) balloon.findViewById(R.id.cinema_title);

    Cinema cinema = MoviesDbAdapter.getCinemaById(marker.getTitle());

    if (cinema != null)
    {
        cinema_title.setText(cinema.title);
    }
}

public void checkGPSEnabled()
{
    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) view.getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(view.getContext().getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*provider*/, 0, 0, this);

    boolean enabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
    // go to the settings
    if (!enabled) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext().getApplicationContext())
                .setMessage(view.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.message_gps_off))
                .setPositiveButton(view.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_gps_enable), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(view.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_gps_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

}
/* Request updates at startup */

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    //getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #map} is not null.
 * <p>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
 * MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services APK on
 * their device.
 * <p>
 * A user can return to this Activity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the Activity may not have been
 * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be stopped or
 * paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this method in
 * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        //map = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        //map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoAdapter());

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void getLocation()
{

    mLog.d("Touch: ");
    checkGPSEnabled();

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*provider*/);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                .zoom(12)
                .build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));

        if (myPosition != null)
        {
            myPosition.remove();
        }
        myPosition = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                .title("Я")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_user)));
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #map} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

public void onUpdate() {

    if(fragmentMode != null)
    {
        if(fragmentMode.equals(modeDefault)){
            cinemas = MoviesDbAdapter.getCinemaAll();
        }
        else if (fragmentMode.equals(modeFavourite))
        {
            cinemas = MoviesDbAdapter.getCinemaFavorites();
        }
        else if (fragmentMode.equals(modeOnline))
        {
            cinemas = MoviesDbAdapter.getCinemaOnline();
        }
        mLog.d("OnCreate: "+fragmentMode);
    }
    else
    {
        cinemas = MoviesDbAdapter.getCinemaAll();
    }

    adapter = new CinemaListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.movies_list_item, cinemas);

    mLog.d("OnCreate: onUpdate "+fragmentMode);
    if(cinemas.length == 0)
    {
        // Load schedules
        //Utils.updateLoadingStatus(view, getString(R.string.message_loading_cinemas));
    }

    if (Settings.getCinemaTypeView() == Settings.CinemaTypeView.Map)
    {
        try
        {
            checkGPSEnabled();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        //ApiDownloader downloader = new ApiDownloader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //downloader.registerAPI(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        if (Markers != null)
        {
            for (Marker marker : Markers)
            {
                marker.remove();
            }
            Markers.clear();
        }

        Markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        if(map != null)
        {
            //нарисовать маркеры кинотеатров
            for (Cinema cinema : cinemas)
            {
                //mLog.d("Cinema: " + cinema.getLatitude());
                Marker cinemaMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(cinema.getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(cinema.getLongitude())))
                        .title(cinema.getId().toString())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_mini)));

                Markers.add(cinemaMarker);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //ApiDownloader downloader = new ApiDownloader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //downloader.registerAPI(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        listViewCinemas = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinemas_list_view);

        int index = 0;
        View v=null;
        if(listViewCinemas != null)
        {
            mLog.d("OnCreate: list not null "+fragmentMode+" "+cinemas.length);

            // save index and top position
            index = listViewCinemas.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            v = listViewCinemas.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

            listViewCinemas.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewCinemas.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

            PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
            listViewCinemas.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solve the issue**

Just separate the fragment with map functionality and not map in two new fragments. The new map fragment extends from SupportMapFragment and allow him to make the view for himlesf:

```
public class CinemaMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements LocationListener {
```

...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    balloon = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_list_item, null);
    return view;
}
```

Then I add my custom functionality (just two buttons) programmatically:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_button, null);
    View vi2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.golist_button, null);

    curLocationBtn = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.cur_location);
    goToList = (Button) vi2.findViewById(R.id.go_back);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(vi, layoutParams);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(vi2, layoutParams2);
```

...

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        //map = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = getMap();
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoAdapter());

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```